# Convert any string to date in R

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Is there some function that will attempt to guess date from string? I found `lubridate:: parse_date_time()`, which sounds like it would do the job, but you need to specify the exact format you are expecting. This is fine if all your strings are similar format, but not if it's human-entered data where anything is possible. I am looking for behavior like Excel, where anything that resembles a date is automatically converted to a date.

For example, `c("April 11, 2020", "Apr 11", "4/11/20", "04-11", "April 11, 1 p.m.", "04/11/2020, 1:00pm")` should all be `2020-04-11`. Do I just have to create an elaborate regex or is there some more intelligent method?

Comment: How would `"04-11"` get the year as 2020? Is there an assumption that if year is not mentioned use the current one?

Comment: The assumption would be the closest year.

Comment: There's `anytime::anydate`, but it picks year 1400 instead of the nearest year. You could easily fix that with a custom function. But there's just no way to know if `04-11` is April 11th or November 4th from a single value. The appropriate `ymd` or `mdy` or `dmy` from `lubridate` works pretty well if you look at the date.

Comment: Try using `lubridate::guess_format()` to get the format for each datetime in your list and then parse it with `parse_date_time()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on @jpmam1's comment, it looks like you can just use `lubridate::parse_date_time` with an unlimited number of patterns. If you specify enough, it will match anything.

```
mydates <- c("April 11, 2020", "Apr 11", "4/11/20", "04-11", "April 11, 1 p.m.", "04/11/2020, 1:00pm")
parse_date_time(mydates,c("mdy","mdY","Bdy","bd","md","Bdh","mdYHM"))
#[1] "2020-04-11 00:00:00 UTC" "0000-04-11 00:00:00 UTC" "2020-04-11 00:00:00 UTC" "0000-04-11 00:00:00 UTC" "2020-04-11 01:00:00 UTC"
#[6] "2020-04-11 01:00:00 UTC"
```

It matches yearless dates with `0000`, something you could fix afterwards.

Comment: I was hoping not to force-feed `parse_date_time` all the possible combinations, but I guess it works. At least until I find another possible format.

Comment: I kind of agree with you, for something that bills itself as "fast and user friendly parsing of date-time data," it leaves a little to be desired.